# Postgresql upsert with JDBC parameter markers

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, upsert

I've got an INSERT statement that works today when called from JDBC using parameters markers:

```
INSERT INTO errorqueue as eq (jobname, sourceid, item) VALUES(?,?,?)
```

In my Java code, I bind the parameters:

```
Connection connection=null;
PreparedStatement stmt=null;
try {

    connection = getConnection();
    stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sqlInsert);

    stmt.setString(1, this.jobName);
    stmt.setString(2, errorItem.getId());
    stmt.setString(3, item.getBody());
    stmt.executeUpdate();
} catch () {
...
}
```

I'm struggling with how I'd need to handle the parameters if I convert this to an UPSERT:

```
INSERT INTO errorqueue as eq (jobname, sourceid, item) VALUES(?,?,?) ON CONFLICT (jobname,sourceid) UPDATE eq SET item=? Where jobname=? and sourceid=?;
```

It's sneaky subtle, but in the INSERT the parameter order is (a,b,c) but in the update, the paramter binding needs to be (c,a,b)

Comment: Well, you now have 6 parameters. Just bind them in the right order.

Comment: What's unclear conceptually is do I need to rebind those same three parameters:  key1, key2, payload   a second time in a different order?

Comment: Yes, you must do that.

Comment: Is there an easy way to avoid the duplicate binding @JBNizet?  our would I have to create a stored procedure for that to work?

Comment: Some libraries have support for named parameters. Spring-JDBC, for example. You would bind the parameter once, by name, and use this named parameter twice in the query.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet - I'm writing for a "least common denominator" JDBC, so I think the best thing for me to do is to pass the 6 parameters, but reorder the INSERT so it matches the UPDATE and is less confusing to maintain, e.g.    INSERT values(item,key1,key2)  UPDATE item Where key1,key2

Answer (score 6):

You don't need parameters in the `on conflict` part at all. Just use `set item = excluded.item`. And you also don't need a `where` clause for the update:

```
INSERT INTO errorqueue as eq 
   (jobname, sourceid, item) 
VALUES(?,?,?) 
ON CONFLICT (jobname,sourceid) 
  UPDATE SET item=exluded.item;
```

You can leave your Java code as it is and Postgres will take care of matching the correct rows.

Comment: Works great, thanks @a_horse_with_no_name - I had made a silly error in my test

Answer (score 2):

The answer #1 is wrong.

INSERT INTO tablename (column1, column2, value) VALUES (?,?,?) ON CONFLICT (column1, column2) DO UPDATE SET value = excluded.value";

the "eq" in the above answer does not belong there.
column1 and column2 belong to some constraint, the insert above will update column1, column2 and value even though the columns1&2 are not listed explicitely.